# Qt rotated image -> polygon

Tags: c++, qt, qimage, qpolygon

I have a `QImage` with center at (x,y) and with size (w,h). I apply a rotation and eventually scaling using `QTransform`. Now is easy to me to put the new image (rotated/scaled) centered at (x,y).

```
QTransform transform = QTransform().translate(0,0).rotateRadians(r).scale(s,s);
QImage image = new QImage(old_image->transformed(transform);
```

I want to have a `QPolygon` with 4 points in the corners of rotated/scaled image. All my attempts failed.

```
QPolygon p = QPolygon(QRect(x-w/2, y-h/2, w, h));
QPolygon p2 = transform.map(p);
```

or

```
QPolygon p2 = transform.mapToPolygon(QRect(x-w/2, y-h/2, w, h));
```

All I got is a polygon in wrong position. Which must be the correct code?

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to images, when we want to rotate a polygon (a rectangle in this case) around its center, we have to use a transformation like

```
T = translate(center).rotate(r).translate(-center)
```

(remember transformations are applied from right to left). Scaling is discarded for the moment. For images such initial translation is implicit.

The issue in this case is that the image *changes* its dimensions after rotating: the size of the new image is the bounding rectangle that contains the rotated pixels, thus the last translate is no longer valid for your case (the `translate(center)`).

Instead, you need something like:

```
T = translate(new_rect.size() / 2).rotate(r).translate(-original_center)
```

To achieve this, you have to split the transformation in two parts (scaling brought back too):

```
T1 = rotate(r).scale(s, s).translate(-center)
T2 = translate(new_rect.size() / 2)
```

since the new rect size can only be computed after applying the first transformation.

Also, see that for `T2` I'm not talking about the center but the *half size*, because the new center will not express the same meaning for images than for polygon (images don't have negative pixel coordinate, for example)

Expressed using Qt API:

```
// Image transformation
auto transform = QTransform().rotateRadians(r).scale(s, s);
auto image = m_image.transformed(transform, Qt::SmoothTransformation);

// Assuming something like: QPainter painter(this);
painter.drawImage(0, 0, image);

// Rect to polygon
const auto rect = m_image.rect();
QPolygonF pol;
pol << rect.topLeft();
pol << rect.topRight();
pol << rect.bottomRight();
pol << rect.bottomLeft();

// First transformation
const auto center = rect.center();
transform = transform.translate(-center.x(), -center.y());
const auto pol2 = transform.map(pol);

// Second transformation
const auto rect2 = pol2.boundingRect();
painter.drawPolygon(QTransform().translate(rect2.width() / 2, rect2.height() / 2).map(pol2));
```

Full code available in [GitHub](https://github.com/cbuchart/stackoverflow/tree/master/39194186-qt-rotated-image-polygon).